# How to perform click event in subview button in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, touch-up-inside

I have 3 class with 3 view controller. And I am adding Second view as a subview in my First View. and In second view there are a button and I want that when I click on that button, a method will called of second view. But my application is crash when I click on that button. Can you help that how I'll perform any event in subview.

Comment: Can you please let me know what message you are getting in log when you app crashes

Comment: Firstly I have received this message in log " -[__NSCFType first:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a155d0" but now I am not receiving any message. And app crash.

Comment: Please check that you have proper connection to your uibutton.

Answer (score 1):

remember this:
 3 Nested views , No.1 contains NO.2 and NO.2 contains NO.3,
you touch the screen, actually No.1 become the first responder, if NO.1's userInteractionEnabled == YES, then NO.2 could get the responder and so on, usually view's userInteractionEnabled is YES, but some are not , like UIImageView ...

Answer (score 0):

you should add your second view like: you should add a uiview IBOutlet on which you show the second View; then make it proprty and add subview of secondView like below;

FirstView.h

@class secondView;
{
secondView *secondViewObj;
}

@property(nonautomic,retain)secondView *secondViewObj;

in the implementation file Firstview.m
@synthesize secondViewObj;

then in you viewDidLoad method you have uiview outlet mysecondsubView in the firstView on which you show the second view.

self.mysecondSubView=[[secondView alloc]initWithNibName@"secondView" nibBundle:nil];